# how does aws lambda invoke work

Tags: aws-lambda, invoke

I am fairly new to lambda and trying to wrap my head around it.  I created a basic hello world function and invoked it through

```
aws lambda invoke
```

My question is

- Dont I have to create an API gateway and expose the lambda function through the API gateway for it work.
- How does aws lambda invoke if I have not created a gateway and exposed the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to necessarily create API gateway for invoking lambda function. Every lambda function is already available to be accessed via Amazon's Web Service using API:

```
POST /2015-03-31/functions/FunctionName/invocations?Qualifier=Qualifier HTTP/1.1
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html for more details.

However, the above API expects that the request payload is signed using aws signature version 4 .  The CLI call `aws lambda invoke` automatically takes care of that piece once you have configured valid access and secret keys.

The API Gateway in front of lambda allows you to add:

- Custom resource names
- Custom authentication schemes (even no authentication if desired)
- Custom way of sending payload
  and more...

In summary, API  Gateway gives you more control over the API resource and can even abstract the user from internals of AWS API.